Can sequences that fail to converge to a finite limit be bounded?
Suppose I have a sequence $$s_1=a$$ $$s_{n+1}=s_n+\frac{1}{7+2s_n^2}$$
This sequence is monotone increasing for all values of $a$ and thus cannot converge to a finite limit.
I am now wondering if it is possible to make the sequence bounded?
I am thinking the answer is no, it is not possible. Since sequences that do not converge to finite limits cannot be bounded?
Edit: I am aware now that sequences that do not converge to finite limits can be bounded. I worded this poorly. I am inquiring if sequences that are monotone increasing that fail to converge to a finite limit can be bounded.

The sequence $a_n = -1/n$ is monotonously increasing and converges to the finite limit $0$. So your sentence "This sequence is ..." contains a false implication.

And on another point, the sequence $(-1)^n$ is very bounded and does not converge. Your thought process in this question is rather unclear, and I am surprised you would not know these immediate counterexamples to some of your claims.

I made a mistake, it should have been $s_{n+1}$, not $s_n+1$.

Well that's edited in the question but has nothing to do with either of my comments.

I appreciate the counterexamples. I was indeed not aware of them and am thankful you brought them to my attention. In particular I was wondering if it is possible for a monotone increasing sequence that does not converge to a finite limit to be bounded. Like the sequence I have listed above. Is there any value of $a$ to bound this limit?

If a sequence of real numbers is monotone and bounded, then it converges. This is the monotone convergence theorem.

The conclusion is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=+\infty, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$.
First, when $a\ge 0$, suppose that $\{s_n\}$ converges, it has an upper bound $M$. Then $s_{n+1}-s_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{7+2s_n^2}\ge\frac{1}{7+2M^2}=const$, which means $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=+\infty$. A contradiction. So $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=+\infty$.
Then, when $a<0$, if $s_n<0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, $s_{n+1}-s_{n}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{7+2s_n^2}\ge\frac{1}{7+2a^2}$. A contradiction. So $\exists n_0, s_{n_0}\ge0$, and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=+\infty$ as well.
